# rails 3 + devise: if registration form has error, how prevent from erasing data in other fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a custom field (referral_code) in my devise registration form. Also have a custom registration controller (so I can redirect to a custom "check your email" page after they register).

It all works fine except if the new user makes a mistake (such as password/confirmation not matching) when the error message is displayed it also erases the referral code field.

How can I have valid data (referral code) stay "filled in" when another field (password or email) throws an error message back to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this as a virtual_attribute. Actually, even if it passed the validation your custom field would not have saved and you would have been even more confused.

Here is a normal devise account model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

Now to get custom fields to save you need to add them as virtual attributes.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :phone_number, :other_field

end
```

Now `:phone_number, :other_field` will save.