# Prevent Devise from erasing entire registration form if a single field fails validation (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, registration

I have the same problem as the person in this post:

[rails 3 + devise: if registration form has error, how prevent from erasing data in other fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642827/rails-3-devise-if-registration-form-has-error-how-prevent-from-erasing-data)

That is to say, Devise erases the entire registration form after a single field fails validation. I am using rails 4, however, and therefore am not sure how to implement the "virtual attributes" solution given to the poster above.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue - don't know why no responders.  Be aware that the "sign_up_params" are now permitted in the application controller, in most cases.  But that hasn't kept the clearing of my fields, either.

Comment: Turned out some other code was setting the values, overriding the auto-repopulate of the fields, in my case.