# How can I retain form data in the event of failed validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

What is happening at the moment is that my form input is lost when the form resets. So for example if someone doesn't fill out a required field, the form reloads and all the previously entered data disappears.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I would like to have all the data that has already been entered to stay entered on the form when the page reloads.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642827/rails-3-devise-if-registration-form-has-error-how-prevent-from-erasing-data) I think this is what I need, but I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical structure for a `create` action:

```
@thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
if @thing.save
  redirect_to @thing
else
  render `new`
end
```

If the `save` is successful, a new request for the just-saved record's `show` link is started which calls the `show` action. On the other hand, if the `save` fails, the response to the client will be a render of the `new` view, but without calling another action. The data from the current `create` action call is used to render that view. Since the client's submitted form data is still contained in `@thing` at this point, the form will be rendered with any data that they submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (and probably preferred by most users) is to validate your data on the client side before the user ever submits the form.

Check out [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) for more information.